# typescript Unexpected token import

Tags: typescript, webpack

I get the following error when using a simple `import` in a node.js base code.
I would like to know what is wrong in my config files and how to fix it:

Error I receive:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { IO } from "fp-ts/lib/IO";
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I am using typescript, here my config files:

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": "."
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: 'index.ts',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.9.4",
    "jest": "^23.5.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "ts-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.18.0"
  }
```

...

```
  "dependencies": {
    "fp-ts": "^1.8.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.3"
  },
```

Comment: I use node v10.3.0

Comment: This shouldn't be happening since your `module` compiler option is set to `commonjs`.  How are you running your program?  `node dist/bundle.js`?

Comment: thanks for your help I was able to fix this issue by pointing to dish in my npm script start, please add it as an answer I would be glad to accept it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your tsconfig you have `"target": "es2017",` Change to `"target": "es5",` as you seem to be running in an enviroment that doesn't support es2017 style modules.

Comment: I tried, now I get a different error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: I use node v10.3.0